# Why do we consider vectors of length $N = 2^n$ for the Quantum Fourier Transform?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, normalization

### Discrete Fourier Transform

Classical Discrete Fourier transform acts on a vector $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_{N-1}) \in C^N$ and maps it to vector $(y_0, y_1, ..., y_{N-1}) \in C^N$ according to the formula
$$ y_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{\frac{2\pi ijk}{N}} x_j, $$
where $k = 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1$.

My understanding of this, is that we are expressing the same vector in new basis (which has the same amount of dimensions as the original one). Moreover, each coefficient standing by the vector from new basis depends on each coefficient from the original basis.

### Quantum Fourier Transform

In Quantum Fourier Transform we consider vecotrs of length $N = 2^n$. So each coefficient is calculated as folows

$$ y_k = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n - 1} e^{\frac{2 \pi ijk}{2^n}} x_j$$

Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform) gives the following example:

> Consider the quantum Fourier transform on 3 qubits. It is the following        transformation:
>
> $$ QFT:|x\rangle \ \rightarrow  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^3}} \sum_{j=0}^{2^3 - 1} e^{\frac{2 \pi ixk}{2^3}} |k\rangle$$

I can't grasp the correspondence between number of qubits $n$ needed to express quantum state and this $N = 2^n$. Nielsen and Chuang in their book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" also write, that "because we take $N = 2^n$ we have the basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, ..., |2^n-1\rangle$ which is computational basis for $n$ qubit quantum computer".

Can you explain me, why we change the basis from $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, ..., |N-1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, ..., |2^n - 1\rangle$? My intuition tels me, that we now operate on such vectors $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_{2^n - 1}) \in C^{2^n - 1}$, but I know this is wrong.

Comment: This isn't particularly unique to the quantum version ─ the (classical) [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) also has this restriction, and it is very often so much faster than the standard DFT that it's cheaper to pad your vector with zeros and use the FFT on a longer input than to run the DFT directly. There are also variations of the FFT that can whittle that down and keep the $O(n\log(n))$ runtime, which could potentially be replicated on the quantum side if you ran things on qudits (not that it makes much sense to explore those, though).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Padding does not result in a FT over Z_N.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty *not that it makes much sense to explore those, though* -- not in the context of quantum computing with qubits maybe, but there are interesting applications of (fast) QFT over qudits, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00782

Comment: @Norbert indeed it doesn't; in some applications the difference matters and in others it doesn't. If you care about the difference and you really want a DFT over $\mathbb Z_p$ for $p$ a large prime, then you're stuck with a slow algorithm already on the classical side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the difference between asking what is the dimensionality of your space $N$ (or equivalently the number of basis states), and how many bit (or qubits) $n$ you have. For each (qu)bit you double the number of distinct basis states, so the relation between $N$ and $n$ is
$$N = 2^n.$$
Counting from $0$ this is $j\in[0,N-1]=[0,2^n-1]$.

As an example, 3 qubits span a space of dimension $2^3 = 8$ because each qubit in the basis state can be represented by a binary $0$ or $1$. So the basis states are
$$|b_1\rangle\otimes|b_2\rangle\otimes|b_3\rangle,$$
where $b_m$ is the $m^\text{th}$ qubit, and can be labeled as $0$ or $1$ in a given basis. In condensed form I might write $|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$ as $|010\rangle$, or I might number the states so this state might be written as $|2\rangle$.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. I think about qubits in similar way like bits. For ex. we can have decimal number j = 10 = (1010)_bin = 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 (where `_bin` is binary notation). So, by analogy, wouldn't the basis for a quantum computer with n quibts be like |2^0>, |2^1>, |2^2>, |2^3>?

Comment: I think you're getting it. $N$ vs $n$ is just the number of total states in a basis vs the number of qubits. This is the same classically when talking about the number of bits vs the number of possible options. I've expanded my answer with an example to (hopefully) clarify this. Let me know if you're still confused and I'll expand on this more.

Comment: So, when we say, that we have basis in form |0>, |1>, ..., |2^n - 1> it is like list of all possible quantum states, that can be represented on $n$ qubits? So it is not like the orthonormal basis (which in our case is made of qubits), where we express vector in form $\alpha |j_1> + \beta |j_2> + ... + \omega |j_n>$? Maybe my problem is about the misuse of word "basis" in these two contexts?

Comment: It is an interesting question, though, whether one can do a QFT over Z_N for any N.

Comment: @Ozaru There are an infinite number of possible states, but a (complete) basis is set a linearly independent states that can be used to represent any state. So for a single qubit you need two states to be the basis, e.g. $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are a basis that can represent any (pure) state $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$. For $n$ qubits you need $2^n$ independent states to form a basis.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch If you have full control of a quantum system with $N$ or more degrees of freedom, then you can do the QFT for any $N$. If your device is a universal quantum computer using $n$ qubits such that $2^n > N$, you simply don't use all states.

This is no different then classical computers. Just because I have 4 Gb of RAM doesn't mean that I can't do math with much smaller numbers. I don't have to use all of my available resources at all times.

Comment: @Punk_Physicist So we begin with choosing $n$ qubits, that we want to work on, and to represent them we need $2^n$ basis states? Like |0>, |1> for $1st$ qubit, |2>, |3> for $2nd$ qubit and so on?

Comment: If you add a 3rd qubit you need to add 4 more states, but states $|4\rangle$,  $|5\rangle$,  $|6\rangle$, and $|7\rangle$ aren't associated with *just qubit 3,* which is why it makes more sense to talk about number of qubits (and the number of states is $2^n$), rather than talking about exponential number of possible states.

Comment: I think I finally get it, thank you very much for all explanations :)

Comment: @Punk_Physicist Obviously, the question is whether you can do the QFT over $\mathbb Z_N$ for any $N$ *efficiently*.  Is it obvious?  What would be the circuit?

Comment: @Punk_Physicist Chapter 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0212002 discusses questions of this kind.  The general anwer seems that this cannot be done efficiently in general (or, at least, is not clear).  There seem to be approximate versions, see Chapter 5.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Agreed that asking whether this is *efficiently* computable is certainly the more interesting/subtle question. As both the reference you give (and Emilio Pisanty's comment above) point out, this is also a bit sticky in classical FT algorithms. However, in practice this usually isn't too much of a pain (e.g. one can pad the vector with zeroes to make the size $N=2^n$)

Comment: @punk_physicist Padding does not result in a FT over Z_N.